# Upserting with a Smart Capture Form Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, smart-capture

I have a very simple page. It has one smart capture form with three fields. It is supposed to insert data into a data extension like below:

[image]

According to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture_form_actions.htm&type=5) page I should be able to customise the actions under a process tab, and even change the form through AMPScript, however I don't see those options or any AMPScript to edit.

The smart form can insert data into the extension correctly, however when I try to update information I get the following error:

> jquery.min.js:2 POST http://cloud.helloworld.com/upsert-test/smartcapture/post 500 (Internal Server Error)

How do I accomplish an upsert, it seems that this used to be possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is for Smart Capture forms for legacy Landing Pages/Microsites within Email Studio. The Cloud Pages Smart Capture documentation is below.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_smart_capture_block.htm&type=5

No upsert option exists in CloudPages currently. The workaround is to create a custom form via HTML on your landing page and then within the form you could implement the upsert via ampscript.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm

Comment: Unfortunately correct, sadly it looks like SFMC is regressing in terms of functionality, but the documentation stays out of date...

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing updated documentation where it says that "Upsert to Data Extension" is now available for Smart Capture.

This is done via Smart Capture Form Actions

Please see additional resources:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_input_parameters_for_upsert_to_data_extension.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_smart_capture_form_actions.htm&type=5